# RubyMine code reformatting not respecting ESLint configuration

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, rubymine, eslint

I have setup ESLint in RubyMine (or any IntelliJ product) and I can see the warning & errors while editing.

[image]

But when I do Code -> Reformat Code, it uses 4 spaces for indentation (the setting in Editor -> Code Style -> Java Script) but I have set 2 spaces in .eslintrc

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "commonjs": true
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ],
  "indent": [
    2,
    2
  ],
  "object-curly-spacing": [
    "always"
  ],
}
```

How to ask RubyMine to use the settings from .eslintrc while formatting code?

Answer (score 2):

You can apply ESLint rules to be used for auto formatter, templates and so on. But, frankly, you have to know where it is. There is zero chance to actually find it if you don't know where to look.

Open your `.eslintrc` and right click (open context menu) in the editor pane. From the options choose `Apply ESLint Code Style Rules`.

See Screenshot below.

Just keep in mind you have to repeat this process every time you touch `.eslintrc`.

[image]

Comment: You saved my next 30 minutes trying to configure Rubymine to play nicely with JSX. Thanks!